# MySQL query - taking ORDER BY off making query 100 times faster

Tags: mysql, sorting, query-optimization

I have found very long query in my system. The MySQL Slow Log says the following:

```
# Time: 2018-07-08T18:47:02.273314Z
# User@Host: server[server] @ localhost []  Id:  1467
# Query_time: 97.251247  Lock_time: 0.000210 Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 41646378
SET timestamp=1531075622;
SELECT n1.full_name AS sender_full_name, s1.email AS sender_email, 
e.subject, e.body, e.attach, e.date, e.id, r.status, 
n2.full_name AS receiver_full_name, s2.email AS receiver_email, 
r.basket, 
FROM email_routing r 
JOIN email e ON e.id = r.message_id 
JOIN people_emails s1 ON s1.id = r.sender_email_id 
JOIN people n1 ON n1.id = s1.people_id 
JOIN people_emails s2 ON s2.id = r.receiver_email_id 
JOIN people n2 ON n2.id = s2.people_id 
WHERE r.sender_email_id = 21897 ORDER BY e.date desc LIMIT 0, 50;
```

The EXPLAIN query shows no **full table scan** and the query using indexes:

```
id select_type table partitions type    possible_keys key       key_len  ref                  rows filtered Extra
1  SIMPLE      s1    NULL       const   PRIMARY       PRIMARY   4        const                1    100.00   Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      n1    NULL       const   PRIMARY,ppl   PRIMARY   4        const                1    100.00   NULL
1  SIMPLE      n2    NULL       index   PRIMARY,ppl   ppl       771      NULL                 1    100.00   Using index
1  SIMPLE      s2    NULL       index   PRIMARY       s2        771      NULL                 3178 10.00    Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1  SIMPLE      r     NULL       ref     bk1,bk2,msgid bk1       4        server.s2.id         440  6.60     Using where; Using index
1  SIMPLE      e     NULL       eq_ref  PRIMARY       PRIMARY   4        server.r.message_id  1    100.00   NULL
```

Here is my SHOW CREATE TABLE queries for the used tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `email_routing` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sender_email_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `receiver_email_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `basket` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `popup` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `tm` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `bk1` (`receiver_email_id`,`status`,`sender_email_id`,`message_id`,`basket`),
 KEY `bk2` (`sender_email_id`,`tm`),
 KEY `msgid` (`message_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1055796 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE `email` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `subject` text NOT NULL,
 `body` text NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `attach` text NOT NULL,
 `attach_dir` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 DEFAULT NULL,
 `attach_subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `attach_content` longtext,
 `sphinx_synced` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `Index_2` (`attach_dir`),
 KEY `dt` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=898001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE `people_emails` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nick` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `key_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `people_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `activity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `internal_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `s2` (`email`,`people_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22146 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `lname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `patronymic` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
 `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `people_type_id` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tags` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `job` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `post` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `profession` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 DEFAULT NULL,
 `zip` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `region` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `address_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_update_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `ppl` (`id`,`full_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=415040 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is the `SHOW TABLE STATUS` output for those 4 tables:

```
Name          Engine Version Row_format Rows    Avg_row_length Data_length Max_data_length Index_length Data_free Auto_increment
email         InnoDB 10      Dynamic    753748  12079          9104785408  0               61112320     4194304   898167
email_routing InnoDB 10      Dynamic    900152  61             55132160    0               69419008     6291456   1056033
people        InnoDB 10      Dynamic    9538    386            3686400     0               2785280      4194304   415040
people_emails InnoDB 10      Dynamic    3178    752            2392064     0               98304        4194304   22146
```

**MySQL Version 5.7.22 Ubuntu 16.04**

However I have noticed one thing - if I take ORDER BY out of the query, *but leaving the `LIMIT`*, then query runs almost instantly taking not more than 0.2 seconds. So I have started to think to run query with no ORDER BY and do sorting by PHP means like that but eventually that seems to complicated as using the LIMIT with no ORDER BY I get wronge range to sort.

Is there anything else I could do to speed up or optimize that query?

**AS AN ALTERNATIVE** I could do sorting and paging by my PHP code. I add addtional columnt into the `SELECT ..., UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.date) as ts` and then do:

```
<?php
...
$main_query = $server->query($query);
$emails_list = $main_query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['ts'], $b['ts']);
}

$emails_sorted = usort($emails_list, "cmp");
for ($i=$start;$i<$lenght;$i++)
{
    $singe_email = $emails_sorted[$i]
    // Format the output
}
```

But when I do that I get

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

at line of `$emails_sorted = usort($emails_list, "cmp");`

Comment: 'using the LIMIT with no ORDER BY I get wrong range to sort' - this should present no problems whatsoever. While it might not be the most appropriate solution, it's perfectly feasible to sort (and paginate) the result in application code.

Comment: Everything looks optimized.  What if you Select all this into a temp table, index e.date and then run a select with an ORDER BY?  Just trying to offer a work around to using PHP.

Comment: The explain in your question, was that on the query with the order by?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for these tables.  Or at least tell us how may rows in each table.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: *"The EXPLAIN query shows no full table scan and the query using indexes"*  Not quite.  `Using index` may not mean what you think, and `type=index, ref=NULL` is a full index scan, which is almost as bad as a full table scan.  `Rows_examined: 41646378`.  The optimizer is choosing a very bad plan for joining to both s2 and n2.

Comment: @Bleach Ok, I will try, but I'm afraid adding an index for each new query would be too slow

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have checked once again, yes it is, but without ORDER BY the EXPLAIN output is the same

Comment: @RickJames MySQL version 5.7.22 Ubuntu

Comment: @RickJames Ok, Done, I have updated the question with those data

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Is this something that needs to be changed on index or I need to change table structure to have less tables and less JOINs?

Comment: I may be wrong on the syntax (not a strategy I need very often) but try these two changes: `JOIN people_emails s2 FORCE KEY(PRIMARY) ON s2.id = r.receiver_email_id
JOIN people n2 FORCE KEY(PRIMARY) ON n2.id = s2.people_id`

Comment: Removing the `ORDER BY` _but keeping the `LIMIT`_ will (in many cases) run a lot faster.  This is because it can stop short.  With the `ORDER BY`, it (usually) must find all rows, then sort, then peel off a few rows.  The problem is collection of all the rows.

Comment: The fatal error while doing the work in PHP simply points out that the intermediate table (before the `ORDER BY` is really big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning, I'm not very familiar with MySQL, in fact I'm mostly projecting MSSQL experience on top of things I (mostly) read about MySQL.

1) Potential workaround: is it safe to assume that email.id and email.date are always in the same order? From a functional point of view this seems logical as emails get added to the table over time and thus have an ever increasing auto-number... But maybe the initial load of the data was in a different/random order? Anyway, if it is, what happens if you `ORDER BY e.id` instead of `ORDER BY e.date` ?

2) Does adding a composite index on `email (id, date)` (in that order!) help?

3) If all of that does not help, splitting the query into 2 parts might help out the optimizer. (You may need to fix the syntax for MySQL)

```
-- Locate what we want first
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results (
    SELECT e.id
           r.basket
    FROM email_routing r 
    JOIN email e ON e.id = r.message_id 
    WHERE r.sender_email_id = 21897 
    ORDER BY e.date desc LIMIT 0, 50 );

-- Again, having an index on email (id, date) seems like a good idea to me

-- (As a test you may want to add an index on results (id) here, shouldn't take long and
--  in MSSQl it would help build a better query plan, can't tell with MySQL)

-- return actual results
SELECT n1.full_name AS sender_full_name, 
       s1.email AS sender_email, 
       e.subject, e.body, e.attach, e.date, e.id, r.status, 
       n2.full_name AS receiver_full_name, 
       s2.email AS receiver_email, 
       r.basket, 
FROM results r 
JOIN email e ON e.id = r.message_id 
JOIN people_emails s1 ON s1.id = r.sender_email_id 
JOIN people n1 ON n1.id = s1.people_id 
JOIN people_emails s2 ON s2.id = r.receiver_email_id 
JOIN people n2 ON n2.id = s2.people_id 
ORDER BY e.date desc
```

Comment: That seems a good solution, I have added the email (id, date) index, and replaced my query with your CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results (SELECT r.* FROM ... and the second one and I don't get long query execution time any more... let me run this for some hours to check at peak load. I tried to ORDER BY id instead of date and it seems ok but it didn't give any difference in the performance so I got back to date order

Comment: A reason that this is likely to be better because of not having to lug around stuff from the other 5 tables.  That is, the trick here is to get to the `LIMIT` as fast as possible, _then_ worry about the rest of the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

If your data comes back that quickly, how about wrapping it... but how many rows are actually GOING to be returned WITHOUT the LIMIT.  Maybe you would still get better performance AFTER such as...

```
select PQ.*
   from ( YourQueryWithoutOrderByAndLimt ) PQ
   order by PQ.date desc 
   LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Comment: Thank you. It is true I'm getting better performance on this, but still 10 times slower as if I would not have ORDER BY at all

Comment: That can't be any faster.  And it prevents any possible optimization of the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  The problem is in collecting all the rows, which the subquery does not eliminate.

Comment: @RickJames, it CAN be faster if it just grabs data.  Once THAT result is done, it will have a smaller set which can build temp index to re-optimize the order by descending and limit.  From 100 times slower to 10 obviously cut 90% off.

Comment: In MySQL 5.7, unless you set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off', the subquery will be merged into the outer query.  So if this turns out to improve things, it must be because somehow a different join order was chosen.  Even if the merge is not done, AFAIK, MySQL will not create an index on the date column of the temporary table.  Hence, the sorting cost should be the same as in the original case.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a case where the MySQL Join Optimizer overestimates the benefits of Block Nested Loop (BNL) join.  You can try to turn off BNL by doing:

```
set optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off';
```

Hopefully this will provide a better join order.  You could also try:

```
set optimizer_prune_level = 0;
```

to force the join optimizer to explore all possible join orders.

Another option is to use STRAIGHT_JOIN to force a particular join order.  In this case, it seems the order as specified in the query text would be good.  Hence, to force this particular join order you could write

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ...
```

Note that whatever you do, you can not expect the query to be as fast as without ORDER BY.  As long as you need to find the latest emails from a particular sender, and there is no information about sender in the email table, it is not possible to use an index to avoid sorting without going through all emails from all senders.  Things would be different if you had information about date in the email_routing table.  Then an index on that table could have been used to avoid sorting.

Comment: I can add date to email_routing. Then I make index just from that new date column?

Comment: You will need an index on (sender_email_id, date).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot use index for order by in your query because

> The query joins many tables, and the columns in the ORDER BY are not
>   all from the first nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows.
>   (This is the first table in the EXPLAIN output that does not have a
>   const join type.)

[MySQL Order By Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html#order-by-index-use)

Comment: While true, it's not the full explanation of the issue.

Comment: Do I need to take it out from WHERE and put into a JOIN?

Comment: How you can put the date into join?

Comment: @user164863 - Jacob is explaining why it is impossible (with any variant of your query) to subsume the `ORDER BY` into an index.  He is not providing a workaround -- there is none.

Comment: @RickJames I didn't get why but CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE was the most efficient solution, the queries became almost instant